# Add calculated column to a pivot_table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

The following is my table

**Date,              Tag,  Value**

1/1/2017,                 T1,    10

1/2/2017,                 T1,    5

1/1/2017,                 T2,    9

1/2/2017,                 T2,    4

After Pivoting, the table becomes:

**Date,                 T1,   T2**

1/1/2017,                 10,    9

1/2/2017,                 5,     4

How can I add a calculated Column (T3) that is T1/T2. In another word, the new table should be as:

After Pivoting, the table becomes:

**Date,                 T1,   T2, T3**

1/1/2017,                 10,    9, 10/9

1/2/2017,                 5,     4, 5/4

Comment: The right name is calculated field, you can follow one of the many tutorials  that you can find on the web. For example this one http://www.contextures.com/excel-pivot-table-calculated-field.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use cell calculation/functions itself for the same once the PIVOT table is prepared.